# YouTube Player API setPlaybackQuality not working as of December 2017

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to force the YouTube Player API to use hd720 resolution.  I noticed since December no matter what I set in the OnPlayerReady, OnPlayerStateChange, or OnPlayerPlaybackQualityChange events I can't get the player to play in HD resolution.

You can see this happen in this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ac0bw99a/).

```
  ytp1.setPlaybackQuality
```

1. Click SHOW QUALITY Switcher
2. click on the hd720
3. expand the player with the [] button
4. after clicking Click gear and you'll see the resolution is not 720

   Any ideas?

Comment: @pattpass It's a different issue now.
Since around december, setPlaybackQuality() stopped doing anything at all. [Here's the official sample](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo), you can see that the quality setting doesn't work, while changing it from the Settings menu (gear icon) does work.